# SQL Alternative to IN operator with variable and between

Tags: sql, variables, sql-server-2012, toad, between

I'm trying to put some variables to an IN Operator but unfortunately it's not working. (found some articles on the internet about it). So what can I do?

I have some stacked queries combined to one. But then I have several times the same argument, well that's no problem. But I have to change all the arguments every times I want to make a new search. So to make it easy I used variables at the top of the query so I can't forget even one to change. And that's working also except for the IN operator. Somehow you can't use multiple variables with the IN operator except when using Dynamic SQL.

Now I have:

```
where [Item No_] not in ('0000900','00009900','00009906')
```

to exclude the products I don't want to see. At this moment there are only 3 but it have to be more, about 20 single once and some are in a range like 00005100 - 00007500 (yes that are 2400). (and in the next query I just need those 2400)

So I tried to `Declare @Exception`, but that's not working. Now I wonder if there is a way to make it work. If not with a variable then at least a combination of a IN and between statement. Or some other way around.

And here is the whole query. I commented out the `@Exception` variable:

```
Declare @Start datetime = '01.04.2015',
        @Ende datetime = '30.04.2015';
/*      @Ausnahme ;
Insert @Ausnahme values (00009000),(00009900),(00009906);
*/

SELECT t1.[Location Code], CAST(t1.Umsatz as DECIMAL(18,2))as Umsatz , CAST(COALESCE(t2.Ersatznachweis, 0) as DECIMAL(18,2)) as Ersatznachweis, CAST(T5.Rückgabe as Decimal(18,2)) as Rückgabe
FROM (
SELECT [Location Code],  SUM(WareBrutto) AS Umsatz
FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT [Location Code], [Document No_] , WareBrutto from [Item Ledger Entry] 
      WHERE [Location Code] between '0000' and '0040' and [Document Date] between @Start and @Ende) t
GROUP BY [Location Code]) as t1

LEFT JOIN
(select [Location Code], sum([Quantity]*Bruttopreis) as Ersatznachweis  from [Item Ledger Entry] 
where [Location Code] between '0000' and '0040' and [Item No_] not IN ('00009000','00009900','00009906') and Gutschrift = '1' and [Document Date] between @Start and @Ende
Group By [Location Code]) as t2 

on t1.[Location Code] = t2.[Location Code] 

Left JOIN
(Select [Location Code], sum(Quantity*PR_Brutto*-1) As Rückgabe
From ( 
select [Location Code], [Item No_], [Quantity] from [Item Ledger Entry] 
where [Location Code] between '0000' and '0040' and [Item No_] not in ('00009000','00009900','00009906') and Rückgabe = '1' and [Document Date] between @Start and @Ende ) as T3

Left Join 
(Select ARTNR, PR_Brutto from dep_prs
where LIdx = '4' and Preisgruppe = '1') as T4 ON T3.[Item No_] = T4.ARTNR
Group By T3.[Location Code]) as T5 on t1.[Location Code] = T5.[Location Code] 

Order by t1.[Location Code]
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a table variable (or parameter if it's a part of a procedure or function) and use it for the `not in` part:

```
DECLARE @NotIn table (
    NotInValues int
)

INSERT INTO @NotIn Values
('00009000'),
('00009900'),
('00009906')
```

and use it in your code like this:

```
where [Location Code] between '0000' and '0040' 
and [Item No_] not IN (select NotInValues from @NotIn) 
and Gutschrift = '1' 
and [Document Date] between @Start and @Ende
```

**Note #1:** for a large number of values, not exists will probably perform better then not in

**Note #2:** If it's a part of a stored procedure you will need to create a user defined table type, and use it to declare the table valued parameter. Also, table valued parameters are readonly, so performing DML statements (insert/update/delete) on them will raise an error.

To create the udt:

```
CREATE TYPE IntegerList As Table
(
    IntValue int
)
```

To declare it in the stored procedure parameters list:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedureName
(
   @IntList dbo.IntegerList READONLY
   -- Note that the readonly must be a part of the parameter declaration.
)
```

Comment: I'll already tried some stuff whit Table, but somehow it's not working. When I try your query I get "Syntax Error near the Table keyword", and the NotInValues is red underlined.

Comment: Both the `declare @NotIn` and the `CREATE TYPE` works in my sql server 2012. can you show what you tried exactly?

Comment: The second part goes a little to deep for my 3rd day of SQL. I'll think I rest this case and put all the exclusions in the query itself. Hope that i get a nice SQL Course someday....