# In statement alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql query below:

```
select *
from a
inner join b on b.id in
(select c.id from c
where c.someid = a.someid)
or a.someid = b.id
```

This is working as expected but the execution time is bad (10 seconds for 4 rows)

I tried many alternatives but their results are different. I'm having hard time having the in statement.

Comment: what is your RDMS ..however you can check with exists..

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777703/sql-alternative-to-in-operator-with-variable-and-between

Comment: in last line you mentioned or..it should be on..

Comment: @anwaar_hell: the `or` is valid. It's part of the join condition (although I that _will_ make it slow)

Comment: You need to tell us the real problem you are trying to solve. Add the definitions of the tables (as formatted `create table` statements). Some sample data (as formatted text) and the expected output based on that sample data.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name ..inner join is mentioned between a and b without on ..is it equal to a left outer join b on a.someid =b.id..? very strage way to write join..:(

Comment: @anwaar_hell: No it isn't. It seems you don't understand the join, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answers. I learned a lot. Unfortunately, the `EXISTS` didn't worked for my case. I used `UNION` and the result time is 2 seconds.

```
select *
from a
inner join b on b.id in
(select c.id from c
where c.someid = a.someid)

union

select *
from a
inner join b on b.someid = a.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks fine. Either `b.id` matches `a.someid` or we must look up `c` entries for that `a.someid`. There is not much we can do about this, it simply is laborious to have to look in two places. There should be indexes on all IDs involved of course, but it would also be advisable to have a composite index on `c(someid,id)` for a quicker lookup.

Apart from that, you can try with `EXISTS` instead of `IN`. One would expect the two to result in about the same execution plan, but some DBMS handle `EXISTS` better than `IN` for some reason.

```
select *
from a
inner join b on 
  b.id = a.someid
  or exists
  (
    select *
    from c
    where c.someid = a.someid
    and c.id = b.id
  )
```

Comment: I would suggest breaking the query using `UNION ALL` to [avoid conditional `JOIN` conditions.](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/how-to-avoid-conditional-joins-in-t-sql/)

Comment: That would be `UNION` in this case, as both conditions may get you the same record and you don't want duplicates. I doubt this would be faster, but it may still be worth a try. Why don't you post this as an answer with an explanation why you assume it to be faster than the original query?

Comment: I'm not actually sure if using `UNION`/`UNION ALL` would be faster. I don't think I need to post a separate answer as I agree with this one with the use of `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1):

check with this..

```
select *
from a
inner join b 
on a.someid = b.id
join table 
(select c.id as id  from c
where c.someid = a.someid) X
on x.id = b.id
```

Comment: `join table (select ...)`? That is invalid SQL

Comment: If you want to breakup the existing join with `OR` into 2 join conditions, you will have to use `LEFT JOIN`